# handle postgress exceptions when inserting from pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy, psycopg2

I am trying to to handle errors which may be thrown by `psycopg2`, so I imported the errors the pipeline was facing and got a weird error when I ran the spider.

pipelines.py

```
from psycopg2.errors import InvalidTextRepresentation
from psycopg2.errors import InFailedSqlTransaction
...
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(
                """INSERT INTO links (url,price) VALUES (%s, %s)""",
                (
                 item["productURL"],
                 item["price"]
))
        except InvalidTextRepresentation, InFailedSqlTransaction:
            pass
```

I got this error directly and the spider didn't run

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Temporarily disabling observer LegacyLogObserverWrapper(<bound method PythonLoggingObserver.emit of <twisted.python.log.PythonLoggingObserver object at 0x7ff963789e80>>) due to exception: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'TypeError'>: _findCaller() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:953:__del__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:270:critical
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:144:emit
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py:131:__call__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py:93:__call__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py:595:emit
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py:154:publishToNewObserver
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_stdlib.py:115:__call__
/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py:1500:log
/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py:1565:_log
]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 953, in __del__
    log.critical("Unhandled error in Deferred:",
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py", line 270, in critical
    self.emit(LogLevel.critical, format, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py", line 144, in emit
    self.observer(event)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py", line 131, in __call__
    observer(event)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py", line 93, in __call__
    self.legacyObserver(event)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 595, in emit
    _publishNew(self._newObserver, eventDict, textFromEventDict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py", line 154, in publishToNewObserver
    observer(eventDict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_stdlib.py", line 115, in __call__
    self.logger.log(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1500, in log
    self._log(level, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1565, in _log
    fn, lno, func, sinfo = self.findCaller(stack_info, stacklevel)
builtins.TypeError: _findCaller() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I changed back to `except:` instead of `except InvalidTextRepresentation, InFailedSqlTransaction:` it worked fine, Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a better to handle the errors of `psycopg2`

Comment: why your query requires 2 params, but you passed tuple that contains 3? This may be a reason and probably is.

Comment: @Vova sorry fixed